# Is there a possibility tor use PhysX.net on an net 6 application?

Tags: c#, wrapper, physx.net

I upgraded my Graphics Engine to net 6, all seems to work, except the PhysiX.Net wrapper which is net 5. I installed it as nuget package and tryed to manually create a reference and copied all neccessary Files to the bin dir. Both trys ended with a Message like : System cannot find the file.

Is there a possibllity to use the wrpper on net 6 ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a net 6 version of PhysX.net on :

https://github.com/stilldesign/PhysX.Net/tree/412-net6

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).